# PHP - Check Date Range/Availability in foreach loop

Tags: php, date

I'm working on a lending system interface for products that are loaned (similar to a library loan system). I'm retrieving a set of products from a database that meet some basic criteria, then I need to display them in a table and flag the ones that are available and those that are not available.

The availability is determined by comparing the date range a user has entered with the series of date ranges for any existing loans for each product. For example a user might enter a start date in MM/DD/YYYY format of `03/26/2018` and an end date of `03/26/2018` and a product might have an existing list of booked date ranges like `10/27/2017 - 05/01/2018,05/10/2018 - 05/21/2018, 08/10/2018 - 12/20/2018` where each date range for existing bookings is separated by a comma.

I'm using a foreach loop to retrieve the initial sets of products to display in my table so I was hoping to incorporate a test within the foreach loop at the same time and identify for each product whether it is available. If there is no overlap between the requested start/end dates and any of the existing product booking dates the product is available, otherwise it is not available.

Here's an example of my current structure:

```
 $loanStartDateRequested = '03/26/2018';
 $loanEndDateRequested = '03/26/2018';

 foreach($records as $record) {
        $existingLoanDateRanges = $record->getField('loanDateRanges');
        // this returns the comma separated values of existing date ranges

       // would like to test and compare the dates here and set a variable if available/not available
 }
```

Comment: If you are comma-separating your date ranges in your database, then your table(s) are not Normalized and you are setting yourself up for a world of hurt in the long term.  If you set up your database tables properly you will be able to write clever queries to do all of the searching/filtering for you -- instead of barfing up huge resultsets and weeding through them with php.  Please take this advice, do research on the topic of normalization, and thank yourself later.

Comment: Agree with mickmackusa.  You are violating basic Relational design sticking a series of dates as comma seperated strings into a varchar.  That design is terribly inefficient, limited, and error prone, not to mention requiring you to look at EVERY product that matches your criteria on the off chance that it is available, when with a proper design your query would efficiently find ONLY products that are available within the desired range, and would do so via SQL WHERE clauses.  Your Loans should be modeled using start_date, end_date DATE columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test availability of product as follows:

```
$loanStartDateRequested = '03/26/2018';
$loanEndDateRequested = '03/26/2018';

foreach($records as $record) {
        $existingLoanDateRanges = $record->getField('loanDateRanges');
        // suppose it returns existing date range as 10/27/2017 - 05/01/2018,05/10/2018 - 05/21/2018, 08/10/2018 - 12/20/2018

        $existingDateRangeArray = explode(",", $existingLoanDateRanges);  // converts comma separated existing date range into array
         $available = 0;              // set variable available = 0

        foreach($existingDateRangeArray as $existingDate){    
              $existingDateArr = explode('-', $existingDate); // again converts daterange, for example, 05/10/2018 - 05/21/2018 into array 

              if(strtotime($loanStartDateRequested) >= strtotime(trim($existingDateArr[0])) && strtotime($loanEndDateRequested) <= strtotime(trim($existingDateArr[1])))
              {
                  $available = 1;
                   break;
               }
        }
 }
```

If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Can the OP handle this task with explosions and iterated function calls in php?  Yes.  Should the the OP do this? No.  Sweet heavens, no.

Comment: @Ishpreet - just confirming that if `$available` = equals 1 then the test is true and the product is available (no date conflicts found)? Or is that the other way around?

Comment: Yes, `$available = 1` means "Product available

Comment: @Ishpreet can you explain the use of break here as well?  Thanks

Comment: @Ishpreet - I've been testing this with a date range of `03/20/2018-03/30/2018` and I'm getting `$available = 1` when it should not be available as that overlaps the date range requested. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes, sure I will explain the purpose of `break`. You mentioned in your question that if requested date falls between any date range `10/27/2017 - 05/01/2018,05/10/2018 - 05/21/2018, 08/10/2018 - 12/20/2018`, means suppose loop is running and requested date match with range `05/10/2018 - 05/21/2018` and requested date is match with second date range in comma separated list. So, we need to break/exit here once we found available. We don't need to check other date ranges.

Comment: If product requested date does not match with any date range, then `$available` value will remain 0, it will not convert to 1, means product not available

Comment: @Ishpreet I was looking for overlaps between the requested date range and any existing loan date ranges. Does your solution handle overlaps?

Comment: You requested date range `03/20/2018-03/30/2018`, it is available because it falls between `10/27/2017 - 05/01/2018` which is first date range in comma separated date range list. Suppose your request date is : `05/05/2018 - 05/10/2018`, its value will be unavailable because `05/05/2018` is not under any date range

Comment: Yes, it handles overlap between requested date range and loan date ranges

Comment: @Ishpreet I'm testing using the date requested range of 03/20/2018-03/26/2018 and an existing loan date range of 03/20/2018-03/30/2018 and I'm getting $available = 1 when it should not be available as these overlap (partially). Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it is not overlapping I think, because requested date `03/20/2018` and `03/26/2018` both are between loan date range `03/20/2018 and 03/30/2018`. Means requested date 03/20/2018 is between loan dates `03/20/2018 and 03/30/2018`, not outside, and even requested date 03/26/2018 (26 March) is also between loan dates `03/20/2018 (20 March) and 03/30/2018 (30 March)`. So, it is available